# Why I need to call an arrow function for update state in this case?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this code to validate a password and email:

```
 const [register, setRegister] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        error: '',
        validation: []
    })

    function validate (e) {
        let valid = true
    
        setRegister((register) => ({ ...register, validation: [] }))
    
        if (register.email === '') {
          setRegister((register) => ({ ...register, validation: register.validation.concat('E-mail is required') }))
          valid = false
        }
    
        if (register.password === '') {
          setRegister((register) => ({ ...register, validation: register.validation.concat('Password is required') }))
          valid = false
        }
    
        return valid
      }
```

Why do I need to use

```
setRegister((register) => ({ ...register, validation: register.validation.concat('E-mail is required') }))
```

instead of

```
setRegister({ ...register, validation: register.validation.concat('E-mail is required') })
```

to add both email and password validation in array validation?

Answer (score 0):

`setRegister` is the asynchronous method, so you can't get the updated value of the `register` after immediately `setRegister`.
So, instead passing the param directly to the setRegister, you need to pass the callback param with the prevstate.

Let's assume both `register.email` and `register.password` are empty so we should setRegister for email and password required validation.
After the first setRegister with just params, `register` won't be updated immediately, so second `setRegister` will be based on the initial `register` value, not the email required validation `register` value.

If we use callback with prev state, it is not based on the `register` value at the time of the calling `setRegister`, but the previous `register` state. Thus finally `register` will be updated to the both email and password required one.

Refer to [Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)